# Decompress SQL Blob Content and return the answer in PushStreamContent .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sqlclient, deflatestream

I am developing a new API in a .NET Core service, the new API is supposed to read a BLOB from SQL table, decompress it using DeflateStream. And then return it (stream it) to the client.

In order not to consume much memory. I am returning a response of type and [PushStreamContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995285(v=vs.118)) so that I could copy the sql stream into the response stream directly without loading the blob in memory. So I ended up with something like that.

```
return this.ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new PushStreamContent(async (outStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {

                        // The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
                        // Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                        {
                            if (await reader.ReadAsync() && !(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
                            {
                                using (Stream streamToDecompress = reader.GetStream(0))
                                using (Stream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(streamToDecompress, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                                {
                                    // This copyToAsync will take for ever
                                    await decompressionStream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
                                    outStream.close();

                                    return;
                                }
                            }

                            throw new Exception("Couldn't retrieve blob");
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "application/octet-stream")
        });
```

The problem here is that the step that copies the deflateStream to the response output stream takes for ever as mentioned in the code. Although I tried the same exact method but with writing the stream to a file instead of copying it to the resp stream and it worked like a charm.

So can you guys help me with this?? Am I wrong about using the PushStreamContent? Should I use a different approach? The thing is that I don't want to load the whole Blob in memory, I want to read it
and decompress it on the fly. [SqlClient Supports streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support) blobs and I want to make use of that.

Comment: By "This copyToAsync will take for ever" do you mean that is hangs indefinitely?  Are you sure the client is reading to the end of the response stream?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , Thank you for answering. Yes, it does hang indefinitely. I know that I can read from the response stream (the once coming from the SqlReader). If I comment out the deflate stream and copy the response stream without decompression to the outStream it works. But it seems like that the deflate stream doesn't read from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a deadlock in PushStreamContent, which I don't pretend to understand.  But I repro'd it and changing

```
await decompressionStream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
```

to

```
decompressionStream.CopyTo(outStream);
```

resolves it.

Here's the full repro:

```
public ResponseMessageResult Get()
{
    var data =  new string[] { "value1", "value2" };

    var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    var msSource = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
    var msDest = new MemoryStream();
    var compressionStream = new DeflateStream(msDest, CompressionMode.Compress);
    msSource.CopyTo(compressionStream);
    compressionStream.Close();

    var compressedBytes = msDest.ToArray();

    var query = "select @bytes buf";
    var connectionString = "server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true";

    
    return this.ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new PushStreamContent(async (outStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@bytes", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = compressedBytes;

                    // The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
                    // Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        if (await reader.ReadAsync() && !(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
                        {
                            using (Stream streamToDecompress = reader.GetStream(0))
                            {
                                //var buf = new MemoryStream();
                                //streamToDecompress.CopyTo(buf);
                                //buf.Position = 0;

                                using (Stream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(streamToDecompress, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                                {
                                    
                                    // This copyToAsync will take for ever
                                    //await decompressionStream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
                                    decompressionStream.CopyTo(outStream);
                                    outStream.Close();

                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        throw new Exception("Couldn't retrieve blob");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    "application/octet-stream")
    });
}
```